# Why isn't $\,\mathcal C[0,1]$ a Banach space in this unusual norm?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I wish to ask the following question:

Let $\mathcal X$ be the normed space $\,\mathcal X=\mathcal C([0,1])$, with norm defined as
$$
\|\,f\|= \max_{x\in[0,1]} x^2 \lvert\,f(x)\rvert.
$$

Why isn't $\mathcal X$ a Banach space?

Comment: It would be nice of you to add some context, what your own thoughts are, how far you have gotten, and where exactly your problem lies. Would make the question sound less like "do my homework for me".

Comment: A Banach space is a complete normed space. 
To show that it is not Banach must find a Cauchy sequence that does not converge to an element of the space?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Stop making pointless edits please. Don't spam the front page with such edits.

Answer (score 5):

Take
$$
f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{x} & \text{if} & \frac{1}{n}\le x\le 1,\\
n^2x & \text{if} & 0\le x\le \frac{1}{n}.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset C[0,1]$, and for $m\ge n$,
$$
\|f_m-f_n\|=\sup_{x\in [0,1]}x^2\lvert\,f_m(x)-f_n(x)\lvert
\overset{\ast}=\sup_{x\in [0,1/n]}x^2\lvert\,f_m(x)-f_n(x)\lvert\overset{\ast\ast}\le \frac{1}{n}\to 0,
$$
owing $\ast\ast$ to the fact that in $[0,\frac{1}{n}$ all $f_n$s are positive and thus $f_n-f_m\leq f_n$, which in turn isn't greater than its value in $\frac{1}{n}$ which is precisely $\frac{1}{n}$, combined with $x^2\leq1$, and owing $\ast$ to the fact that $x^2\cdot\frac{1}{x}$, which is what we would be taking the supremum of in $[\frac{1}{n},1]$, is $x$, and values greater than its supremum there, which is 1, are attained bu $n^2x\cdot x^2$ in $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$, at least for $n$ sufficiently big. But the sequence does not converge is $C[0,1]$, since it is not bounded in the standard $C[0,1]$ norm.

Comment: @GiulyB hopefully my edit to the answer can help you solve your problems understanding it :).

Comment: I have approved it.

Comment: why is not bounded in the standard norm?

Comment: @GiuliaB what would this converge to? $\frac{1}{x}$, right? Is that bounded? No. If this doesn't convince you, for $n$ sufficiently big you can get $f_n$ to attain any value since you can get as close as you want to 0 with the part where it is $\frac{1}{x}$. More formally, take $M\geq0$. You can find $n_0$ for which if $n\geq n_0$, $\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{M}$. This means that $f(\frac{1}{M})=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{M}}=M$. And not for only one value, for infinitely many values, from $n_0$ onwards. So the supremum norm (standard norm, as Yiorgos put it) of $f_n$ is above $M$ for all those $n$s.